# Can someone - help me - create a titlepage for a master thesis

Tags: titles

our university wants us to use an uniform title-page ([link to a folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1g-OwG92ywVWsCKxvTRHoKwRNas65Hg4p?usp=sharing) with a .dotx, pdf and the required images).

Is someone willing/capable of setting me on the right track to mimic this **A4-page** in Tex? It does not have to be a /maketitle-thingie. A single *title.tex* is more than enough for me.

If I were to fill out the text-part, it would read

```
TITLE
SUBTITLE
Word count: 00,000

Loosely Subtle
Studentennumber: 123456
Supervisor(s): Prof. dr. Charles Francis Xavier , dr. Victor von Doom
A dissertation submitted to Ghent University in partial fulfilment of the requirements for the degree of Bachelor/Master/Doctor of …
Academic year: 2018 - 2019
```

The pixelperfecter the titlepage, the better. The font in the .dotx appears to be *Arial* but really is **Gentium** (also included in the online folder).

Thank you for getting me on the right track! As I said before, I plan to release these files to the public domain so others can benefit from your work...

[image]

Comment: What do you need to get starter yourself? "Please do this for me" is far outside the scope of this community. You should familiarise yourself with our format: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Comment: At the moment this question says "please do this for me" and while I'm sure that is an unfair assessment of your intentions, that impression does not particularly encourage people to write an answer. That is not to say that no one is going to try and answer your question, but you can make it much easier for people to help you if you could point out specifically what your troubles are with this title page. At first glance most things look fairly basic, without having tried anything I'd say the only tricky thing is the separator between title and subtitle. Why don't you share a first attempt?

Comment: BTW: According to the PDF information the font in the linked PDF version of the title page is indeed Arial and not Gentium. Gentium is a serif font and the font on the page is sans serif...

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280

Comment: Please, avoid adding “solved”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only took me 4 hours to find out that `smallcaps` can not be combined with 
`textbf`.

```
% !TeX spellcheck = nl_NL
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}    % interlinie 1.5
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}           % witregel in plaats van insprong   

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}               % Nederlands
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % speciale karakters

\usepackage{lmodern}                    % font
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % figuren
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}        % Context sensitive quotation facilities


% titelpagina specific
\usepackage[pass,a4paper,margin=1cm,left=0cm,bindingoffset=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}         % change fontcolor
\usepackage{tikz}                       %  position images pixelperfect on the page
\usetikzlibrary{calc}                   %% with this library

\usepackage[implicit=false,             % Only parse hyperlinks
hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=210mm}   %%% <--- here

\begin{titlepage}

    %    \vspace*{-100px}
    %            
    %    \begin{flushleft}
    %        \hspace{-30px}
    %        \includegraphics[width=.4\textheight]{./img/letteren}
    %    \end{flushleft}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,
    xshift=1.6cm]
    at (current page.north west) %left bottom corner of the page
    {\includegraphics[width=320px]{./img/letteren}}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \vspace{6cm}

    % title

    { \color[RGB]{30,100,200}
      \huge
            \underline{
                \textbf{
                    \hspace{-20px}
                    Some fancy title
                } % end boldface
            } % end underline
        \newline
        \large subtitle
    } % end color

    \normalsize Aantal woorden: 00.000

    \vspace{3cm}
    {\Large \textbf{Loosely Subtle}}
    \newline Studentennummer: 123456789

    \vspace{0.3cm} 
    { \large \textbf{Promoteren: Prof. dr. Charles Francis Xavier , dr. Victor von Doom} }
    \newline Template for stackEchange

    \vspace{0.3cm}
    Academiejaar: now - then    

    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,
    xshift=1.8cm]
    at (current page.south west) %left bottom corner of the page
    {\includegraphics{./img/footer}}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry       %% <--- and here

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please note that font commands such as `\Large` are switches and don't take an argument.

Comment: @samcarter, I have a feeling you are trying to say something to me but I have no clue what it is :) I am a super Latex n00b who copy/pasta'd above layout together with pieces from the interweb.

Would you please explain the comment above?

Comment: What I mean is that you should not write `\Large{text}` which is wrong syntax, but `\Large text`. If you want the font only be applied to part of the text and not to the rest of the document you can do `{ \Large text }`

Comment: Basically just use those font size commands like you use `\color[RGB]{30,100,200}`

Comment: just `\huge` instead of `\huge{}`, the `{}` are unnecessary.

Comment: May I edit your answer to remove unnecessary `{}`?

Comment: sure, go ahead and edit.
The community can only benefit...

Comment: I removed some the superfluous `{}`. Typically `hyperref` should be loaded as one of the last packages.

Comment: I just copy-pasted above code and nothing changed :)

Thank you very much for the edits, @samcarter

Comment: You're welcome! And happy TeXing :)

Answer (score 0):

Using RTF to TEX gives me this rough layout which works in Xelatex but it needs lots of tuning[image]

```
%&pdfLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,left=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{color}
\geometry{paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=210mm}

\begin{document}
\textbf{ }\newline{}%
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true]{img_header}\newline{}%
\vspace{120pt}
\newline\normalfont
\leftskip=1cm
{\huge{}\textbf{\emph{\texttt{<} TITEL \texttt{>}}}}\newline
{\large{}\textbf{\texttt{<} SUBTITEL \texttt{>}}}\\
\vspace{12pt}
Aantal woorden: \texttt{<} 00.000 \texttt{>}\\
\vspace{96pt}

{\large{}\texttt{<} Voornaam + Achternaam auteur \texttt{>}}\\
Studentennummer: ...
\vspace{12pt}
Promotor(en): Prof. dr. \texttt{"}Voornaam Achternaam\texttt{"} , Prof. dr. \texttt{"}Voornaam 
Achternaam\texttt{"}\\
\vspace{12pt}
\texttt{<} Selecteer type proef \texttt{>} voorgelegd voor het behalen van de graad 
\texttt{<} selecteer graad \texttt{>} in de ...\\
\vspace{12pt}
Academiejaar: 2000 - 2000\\
\vspace{144pt}

\includegraphics[width=150pt, height=120pt, keepaspectratio=true]{img_footer}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One should probably mention, that this is horrible code. It should only be used as a good example of bad auto-generated code.

Comment: @Johannes_B I totally agree its an example of how not to use a decompiler to recompile but it seems to have spurred an answer from the OP without spoon feeding :-)